# Make a view inside a frame an ontouchlistener

Tags: android, android-fragments, ontouchlistener

How can I create an onTouchListener for a frame that only houses a fragment?  I don't need to inflate an activity_main file as it will already be displayed by the time this fragment is called.  If I try to inflate the frame itself it throws a "expected resource of type layout" error.

The fragment will be activated when a user touches a button and the fragment should open in the frame.  The frame also needs to be able to listen to touch events.

This is what my Fragment and onCreateView for the fragment looks like right now:

```
public class TeacherFragment extends Fragment {

public final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

public void onAttach(Activity myActivity){

    Log.v(TAG, "in TeacherFragment - onAttach, activity is: " + myActivity);
    super.onAttach(myActivity);
}

/**
 * This method will only be called once when the retained
 * Fragment is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

/**
 * This method will be called only when
 * Fragment is attached and ready to display the view.
 */
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle SavedInstanceState){

    if(container == null) {
        Log.v(TAG, "container is null. No need to inflate.");
        return null;
    }

    View v = container.findViewById(R.id.assignment_view);
    v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onShortPress: " + event.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "Testing Short click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onLongPress: " + event.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "Testing Long click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return v;
}  //end onCreateView
```

}

Here is my activity_main.  I am trying to use the assignment_view frame only for this Fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:baselineAligned="false">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_menu_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:layout_weight=".3">
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="8dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/assignment_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00BBFF"
    android:layout_weight="8">
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So what's the issue? You try to set touch listener, but it doesn't work or what?

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: Can you post your code where you start the fragment?

Comment: I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only use `inflate()` on a file.  One that's in your "layout" folder.  This is what the error message is telling you.  Without spending a lot of time looking at this, you probably want this

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.assignment_view);
```

As far as inflating your "activity_main.xml" file, it's probably better to inflate it here than rely on what was inflated in the calling activity.

Comment: I should have mentioned, sorry!  When I attempt to findviewbyid it comes back as "cannot resolve method".  I have imported the android view class so I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: try `container.findViewById...`

Comment: That gives me a stable build so its in the right direction!  But the onTouch events aren't firing.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi just realized I wasn't dedicating a full xml file to my container which in this case was assignment_view.  Rather was just trying to use the frame assignment_view as my inflation method.  I have added a separate file to insert into that container.  Thanks again!